# Java snippet based AST-Manipulation before/during compilation

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

The question is whether the functionality I describe below already exists, or whether I need to make an attempt at creating it myself. I am aware that I am probably looking at a lot of work if it does not exist yet, and I am also sure that others have already tried. I am nevertheless grateful for comments such as "project A tried this, but..." or "dude D already failed because...". If somebody has an overall more elegant solution, that would of course be welcome as well.

I want to change the way I develop (private) Java code by introducing a multiplexing layer. What I mean by that is that I want to be able to create library-like parameterizable AST-snippets, which I want to insert into my code via some sort of placeholders (such as annotations). I am aware of project https://projectlombok.org/ and have found that, while I find it useful for small applications, it does not generally suit my requirements, as it does not seem possible to insert own snippets without forking the entire project and making major modifications. Also lombok only ever modifies a single file at a time, while I am looking for a solution that will need to 'know' multiple files at a time.

I imagine a structure like this:

- `Source S`: (Parameterizable) AST-snippets that can be included via some sort of reference in `Source A`.
- `Source A`: Regular Java-Code, in which I can reference snippets from `Source A`. This code will not be compiled directly, as it is lacking the referenced snippets, and would thus throw a lot of compile time exceptions.
- `Source T`: Target Source, which is an AST-equivalent copy of `Source A`, except that all references of AST-Snippets have been replaced by their respective Snippet from `Source S`. It needs to be mappable to the original `Source A` as well as the resolved snippets from `Source S`, where applicable, as most development will happen there.

I see several challenges with this concept, not the least of which are debuggability, source-mapping and compatibility with other frameworks/APIs. Also, it seems a challenge to work around the one-file-at-a-time limitation, memory wise.

The advantage over lombok would be flexibility, since lombok only provides a fixed set of snippets for specific purposes, whereas this would enable devs to write own snippets, or make modifications to getters, setters etc. Also, lombok 'quirks' into the compilation step, and does not output the 'fused' source, afaik.

I want to target at least *javac and eclipse's ecj* compilers.

Comment: You've seen how complex projectlombok is, and what you want is considerably more complicated than that. Start with the lombok codebase and take it from there if you really want to go down this route. Also read [lombok wiki on resolution](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/wiki/LOMBOK-CONCEPT:-Resolution).

Comment: You are fast as lightning, I will give you that. I might start from lombok, but as you have stated a bunch of times, the one-file-limitation is there for a reason, and afaik, it has to do with the way lombok hooks into the compilation. I haven't taken a more detailed look, but I imagine, that my variant should be easier in that regard, though a lot more compilcated in others (like how to map soruce A to source T, which is not a problem for lombok).

Comment: What you describe with AST snippets sounds a lot like eclipse JDT refactorings that are based on a specific DSL for the snippet references. Maybe you could also start from there.

Comment: I do see that the resolution of identifiers is a later step, relative to AST-creation, which is why I am explicitly looking to modify the AST with information available at that point in time, which to my knowledge, is only the raw sources, the classpath, the AST itself, as well as (in theory) some sort of token stream, but I am not even sure, if that stream is still open after AST-creation. Theoretically the AST itself and the respective sources should suffice, though.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker Thanks for the hint. I will take a look at that.

Comment: [Eclipse Object Teams](https://www.eclipse.org/objectteams/) might be what you are looking for (it works differently than Lombok and as you imply in the question, but you don't have to implement your tooling yourself; instead, you use Java/OO with another layer of abstraction, which hopefully meets your needs).